# Specific selection of data from two SQL tables using Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a mysql database and i want to make a specific selection. Here is the scenario:

**First table**

Road list data about cargo vehicles.

```
roadListNumber(primary_key), vehicle, driver, startWorkTime, endWorkTime and so on.
```

**Second table**

Cargo zones mapped with the primary key of the first table.

```
roadListNumber(foreign_key), zoneId, timeInside, spentMoney and so on.
```

The problem is that not every vehicle goes to the cargo zones so some of the road lists are not mapped with cargo zones (the second table ) and here comes my problem and the question:

How can i select all the roadlist  from first table and join the result with the second table ( cargo zones ) **without** skipping the roadlist which are not mapped with cargo zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already using the correct word (JOIN). You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in order to fetch all the records in the first (or *left*) table, and relate them to their corresponding records from the second (or *right*) table according to the `ON` clause.

Notice the usage of the *left* and *right* table terms here and how it relates to *`LEFT`*`OUTER JOIN.`

If there's no matching record on the second table, you will get `NULL` on the second table's columns in the result set.

```
SELECT * FROM roadlist rl 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cargozones cz ON rl.roadlistnumber = cz.roadlistnumber
```

There are many kinds of `JOIN`. If you were using an `INNER JOIN`, for instance, you would only get the records that have a match on the second table.

See this blog post for a good visual explanation on how do SQL joins work: [Coding Horror: A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to get data... also use `GROUP BY` to avoid repeated data..

```
SELECT rl.roadListNumber,rl.vehicle,cz.zoneId,cz.spentMoney  
FROM road_list rl 
LEFT JOIN cargo_zone cz on (rl.roadListNumber=cz.roadListNumber) 
GROUP BY rl.roadListNumber
```